# Evidence to bring to the second immigration interview after a 10 year ban?

Tags: usa, immigration, refusal

During my most recent interview last year I was told I was on a 10 year ban because I overstayed my visa by a year and half and was over 18 years old. Even though I told the consular officer that my visa was under my parents passport and traveled at the age of 13 and left when I was 20 and had no choice but to wait until I had a stable situation before going back to Europe, I was still considered to have a 10 l-year ban.

Not knowing I had the 10-year ban, I still went back to the States to visit my family at least 12 times within the last ten years and answered no and all questions on the ESTA  since I didn’t know I overstayed my visa and that I had a 10-year ban.

Now I am in the process of re-applying again but I'm scared that the officer will ban me for life if they consider that I should have known.

What can I do to prove them that I had no idea so it wouldn’t affect my IR1 immigration visa?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You might need an immigration lawyer.

Comment: I am trying to avoid  that....because i have nothing to hide ......I told the truth. I am just wondering if they would mention it and ask me since they didnt last time.

Comment: Were you asked about overstays in the paperwork for your previous travel?

Comment: I was ask why i overstayed 10 years ago but it didnt make a difference since I was over 18 eventhough I didn’t know at the time i was overstaying my visa since my visa was under my parents passport not mine.

Comment: And during my last interview they did not ask me about my previous trips in the last 10 years to the us, I did not overstayed the times I went on vacation....I would only stay for three weeks not more.

Comment: And I clearly stated all of my last trips to the US the last 10 years on my visa application

Comment: @Paul: I think PatriciaShanahan was asking whether you were asked about overstays on your ESTA applications

Comment: @Patricia-shanahan no I was not asked before.

Comment: Nor did I ever over stay any of my ESTA.

Comment: @Paul The issue is not the ESTA stays, but the long overstay on the original visa. I agree that you may need a lawyer, but it is going to be easier to argue that you were not aware of the ban than to argue that you were not aware as a young adult that you did not have a visa or a green card.

Comment: @Patricia-shanahan: thanks.... i agree.....either way they are the one s that told me about the bar in the first place last year when I did my first interview last year.

Comment: @Paul - you have nothing to hide and say the truth: but you may need to hire an experienced immigration lawyer to help you explain your situation to immigration officer in a way beneficial to you, in the terms immigration officer thinks. Job of immigration officer is not to help you but to prevent illegal immigration. OTOH, job of your lawyer is to help YOU.

Answer (score 2):

You should have no problem getting an immigrant visa if you don't have a ban. Your 10-year 9B ban for accruing 1 year of unlawful presence and departing is over. What other ban can you have?

There is no ban for entering the US while you are under a ban, if that's what you're worried about. They shouldn't have let you in, but they did, and there is no ban for having gotten in like that. Whether you knew that you were under a ban or not is also not relevant by itself.

One ban to consider is the lifetime 6C ban for fraud or misrepresentation. The places where there may potentially have been misrepresentation are on the ESTA applications and at the port of entry on your travels when you entered on the Visa Waiver Program. That's why some people asked you in comments whether you were asked a question about overstay on your ESTA applications (e.g. something like "Have you ever stayed in the United States longer than the admission period granted to you by the U.S. government?"). The questions on an ESTA application have changed many times over the years, and I don't know what exact questions you got (do you know?), but if it asked about overstay, and you answered no, that could be misprepresentation.

Comment: @user102008- I just remember the last ESTA I did and I checked it did ask if I ever stayed and I said no because back in 2015 I was not aware of the ban only a year later I found out......so once I did my interview at the embassy in 2016 and was rejected my visa I received a update mail from ESTA stating that my current ESTA stating that I was no longer able to travel to the us under the visa waiver program. So I have not been back since 2015.  And no I do not have any other bans.

Comment: @Paul: Whether you were aware you had a ban is not relevant because that's not what the question asked. I think you're saying that the question asked if you ever overstayed. (I am not sure from your description "it did ask if I ever stayed".) Were you not aware that you overstayed?

Comment: @user102008- Yes sorry I meant overstay no stay. No I was not aware of it since my visa was under my parents passport and never knew until I asked.

Comment: @Paul: But you were an adult living in the US for years and you believed the whole time that your status didn't expire until after the date you left? You should be prepared to deal with potentially having a ban for misrepresentation on your ESTA applications.

Comment: no I never asked since the whole family was there, the only reason why I left was because I couldn’t afford college in the US and went back to Europe.

Comment: @Paul, the saving grace for you is that AFAIK they tend to limit the ban to misrepresentations made directly to an officer (this is one reason why the US has interviews for almost all visas) so it is possible the subject of your visits simply won't come up. If it doesn't come up you shouldn't raise the issue yourself. If it does come up (perhaps a CBP officer left a note) listen carefully to the questions and answer what you are asked as honestly as you can. He'll be wanting to know if you might have lied to a CBP question, being brutally honest is a way to persuade him you wouldn't have.

Comment: @Dennis-for sure like I said I have nothing to hide if they ask me I will answer the truth which is that I had no idea about the ban while I was doing my vacation trips to the Us. Is there anything I could prepare to show that I was in Europe the past 10 years ?

Comment: @Paul: You keep getting hung up on whether you knew about the ban but that is not relevant to the issue. The issue is whether you knew about your *overstay*. You could have no ban but still overstayed. You answered on the application that you never overstayed, which means you don't think you even overstayed for 1 day ever.

Comment: @Paul: You don't have to show you were in Europe the past 10 years. No matter where you were, if it has been mathematically 10 years since your departure, the unlawful presence ban triggered by that departure is over. The question is whether you have a lifetime ban for misrepresentation.